# How to Set Session in Form Request Validation Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

I create validation using laravel form request file and I want to set session in laravel request file and send the session with validation error to blade view.. can I do that ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Using Laravels validation whether that be within the `App\Http\Requests` or in the controller itself using

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required
]);
```

Will automatically return errors back to the view itself for you to display within the `$errors` variable.

If you're calling the `Validator::make()` method yourself and wish to check the errors manually and redirect. You can do this by using

```
$validator = Validator::make($request, [...]);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
}
```